# I installed win vista home, need to switch to win vista pro with no data loss

Tags: windows, windows-vista

I installed windows vista home yesturday and just finished installing and configuring a bunch of programs. I went to go activate windows and it said my product key was for windows vista pro, not home.

Is there a way to change the edition without losing data? Thanks!

P.S. I have acces to a windows vista pro install disc if I need it.

Comment: This is what Anytime Upgrade is for.

Comment: Actually, from what I'm seeing online, the Vista Anytime Upgrade infrastructure was retired in august 2009, but Op should be able to use a traditional inplace upgrade: http://support.microsoft.com/KB/2255099, or install off retail media, using a pro key.

Comment: Checked it. Only works on windows 7 now.

Comment: Ill try that. Come back if it works. Also, is this the right place to ask this question? I am used to stackoverflow and I thought that this was for general computer questions, am I wrong?

Comment: your question is on topic, so not sure why the downvote, other than that someone probably though you could have researched the question more thoroughly yourself. I must admit, I was surprised that the anytime upgrade doesn't work any more.

Comment: Upvoted the question to restore to 0 points. Valid question with no easy answer.

Comment: Do you have external media to backup all your files to, just in case things go wrong? If so, you could use Transfer my settings to a new pc wizard to make a backup of your settings, and backup the rest to the external media after which you can perform a clean install.

Comment: Thank you for your help but the easiest solution I found was to just get a product key for windows vista home. I just did that instead, didn't feel like going through the whole process and I had a friend who was kind enough to give one to me.